# Sentencia IF con posiciones x

Tags: java

Buenas,
quiero montar una sentencia if de la siguiente manera:

Tengo la posicion xInicial y la posicion xFinal.

Mi objetivo es que el objeto vaya desde xInicial a xFinal sumando en positivo y cuando llegue a xFinal sume en negativo y cuando vuelva a llegar a la xInicial más de lo mismo.

En resumen,que vaya de xInicial a XFinal como si rebotara.

¿Alguna idea?

```
   xinicial = 0;
   xfinal = 5;
    void update(){
       if(xinicial < xfinal){ 
          xinicial += 1;
       }
   }
```

La idea es que cuando xInicial sea = 5 pues se reste hasta 0 y luego de nuevo a sumar,infinitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que quieres hacer es necesario una repetitiva, en este caso un `while`, ya que un `if` es una condición que se repite solamente una vez. Es decir, tú código solo sumaría 1 a *xInicial*. No sé exactamente hasta cuando quieres que esté rebotando, pero suponiendo que esté siempre rebotando sería algo así:

```
int xinicial = 0;
int xfinal = 5;
int objeto=0;
boolean vuelta=false;
 void update(){
   while(true){
      if(xinicial<xfinal && !vuelta){
         objeto++;
        }else if(xinicial==xfinal){
          vuelta=true;
          objeto--;
        }else if(xinicial>0 && vuelta){
          objeto--;
        }else{
          vuelta=false;
        }
      System.out.println(objeto);
   }
```

En el `while(true)` tienes que poner la condición que se tiene que cumplir para que siga ejecutándose, en este caso, como ya he dicho, se va a ejecutar todo el tiempo ya he puesto `true` así que se va a cumplir siempre.

Comment: Esto se parece mas a lo que andaba buscando